# Table view is taking up the whole view instead of taking input width and height

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, restkit

I want a relatively small table view in my app. But I seem to have no luck because the table view is taking up the whole screen.

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{
 UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 60.0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

   self.view = tableView;
 }

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *MyCellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];

if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyCellIdentifier];
}

return cell;
   }

  - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 5;
  }
```

Comment: is it inside a UIViewController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad method replace `self.view = tableView` to

```
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create a property and give a name to your tableView:

> @property(strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView* myTableView;

And after that you have to connect the delegate and do the

> @synthesize myTableView;

Then use your code like that:

> myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 60.0) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

Without this -> self.view = tableView;

Answer (score 0):

I often ran into this problem. The best way in my experience to handle this, is to create a container view controller, that has the table vc as child vc.

I've created a simple class to manage that. You can just setup the vc in IB.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface ContainerViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentViewPlaceholderView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIViewController *contentViewController;

@end

#import "ContainerViewController.h"

@interface ContainerViewController ()

@property (assign, nonatomic)BOOL isContentVCAdded;

@end

@implementation ContainerViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setup
{
    self.isContentVCAdded = NO;
}

- (void)insertAndShowContentVC
{
    [self removeAllChildVCs];
    self.contentViewController.view.frame = self.contentViewPlaceholderView.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:self.contentViewController];
    [self.contentViewPlaceholderView addSubview:self.contentViewController.view];
    [self.contentViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    self.isContentVCAdded = YES;
}

- (void)removeAllChildVCs
{
    for (UIViewController *vc in self.childViewControllers) {
        [vc willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
        [vc.view removeFromSuperview];
        [vc removeFromParentViewController];
    }
}

- (void)setContentViewController:(UIViewController *)contentVC
{
    _contentViewController = contentVC;
    if (contentVC == nil) {
        [self removeAllChildVCs];
    }
    else {
        [self insertAndShowContentVC];
    }
}

#pragma mark Lifecycle

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (nil != _contentViewController && !self.isContentVCAdded) {
        [self insertAndShowContentVC];
    }
} 

@end
```

You just need to create a `contentViewPlaceholderView` (in IB or code) that has exactly the frame you want the table view to have. Then you just create your table vc as you like and set it as `contentViewController` of the `ContainerViewController`